# Non blocking way of adding a work item to array or list

Tags: c++, c++11, threadpool, future, lock-free

**Edit:**

I now have finished my queue (overcoming the problem described below, and more). For those interested it can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90628/lockless-fifo-queue-using-c11). I'd be happy to hear any remarks:). Please note the queue isn't just a work item queue, but rather a template container which of course could be instantiated with work items.

**Original:**

After watching [Herb Sutter's talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism) on concurrency in C++11 and 14 I got all excited about non blocking concurrency.

However, I've not yet been able to find a solution for what I considered a basic problem. So if this is already on here, please be gentile with me.

My problem is quite simple. I'm creating a very simple threadpool. In order to do this I've got some worker threads running inside the `workPool` class. And I keep a list of `workItems`.

How do I add a work item in a lock free way.

The non lock free way of doing this would of course be to create a mutex. Lock it if you add an item and read(and lock of course) the list once the current work item is done.

I do not know how to do this in an lock free way however.

Below a rough idea of what I'm creating. This code I've written for this question. And It's neither complete, nor error less:)

```
#include <thread>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

class workPool
{
public:
    workPool(int workerCount) :
        running(1)
    {
        for (int i = workerCount; i > 0; --i)
            workers.push_back(std::thread(&workPool::doWork, this));
    }

    ~workPool()
    {
        running = 0;
    }
private:
    bool running;
    std::vector< std::thread > workers;
    std::deque< std::function<void()> > workItems;

    void doWork()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            (*workItems.begin())();
            workItems.erase(workItems.begin());
            if (!workItems.size())
                //here the thread should be paused till a new item is added
        }


    }

    void addWorkitem()
    {
        //This is my confusion. How should I do this?
    }

};
```

Comment: Providing your current code will help people help you

Comment: I've been working with a multi threaded Qt app for quite while and haven't used a mutex yet. If you have full control of your code, aren't there quite a few ways to give a thread exclusive access to resources other than locking it?

Comment: Are you asking for a completely platform independent solution?  If so you can use [`std::atomic`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/), specifically the compare and exchange functions, to insert a work item into a data structure (linked list?) in an atomic, non-locking way.  However on platforms that, for example, support GCD I would just use a serial dispatch queue

Comment: @i_am_jorf Well I'd prefer a platform independend solution yes:). Futures, promises and atomices are designed to do this kind of thing right?

Comment: @user3528438 Well I think that's rather impressive. However the qt library is different and more extensive than the c++11 one. So if you'd know a solution to this particular problem i'd be happy to hear it:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen Herb's talks recently and I believe his [lock-free linked list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmxkPChOcvw) should do fine. The only problem is that `atomic< shared_ptr<T> >` is not yet implemented. I've used the `atomic_*` function calls as also explained by Herb in his talk.

In the example, I've simplified a task to an int, but it could be anything you want.

The function `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` takes three arguments: the item to compare, the expected value and the desired value. It returns true or false to indicate success or failure. On failure, the expected value will be changed to the value that was found instead.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

// Untested code.

struct WorkItem { // Simple linked list implementation.
    int work;
    shared_ptr<WorkItem> next; // remember to use as atomic
};

class WorkList {
    shared_ptr<WorkItem> head; // remember to use as atomic
public:
    // Used by producers to add work to the list. This implementation adds
    // new items to the front (stack), but it can easily be changed to a queue.
    void push_work(int work) {
        shared_ptr<WorkItem> p(new WorkItem()); // The new item we want to add.
        p->work = work;
        p->next = head;

        // Do we get to change head to p?
        while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&head, &p->next, p)) {
            // Nope, someone got there first, try again with the new p->next,
            // and remember: p->next is automatically changed to the new value of head.
        }
        // Yup, great! Everything's done then.
    }

    // Used by consumers to claim items to process.
    int pop_work() {
        auto p = atomic_load(&head); // The item we want to process.
        int work = (p ? p->work : -1);

        // Do we get to change head to p->next?
        while (p && !atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&head, &p, p->next)) {
            // Nope, someone got there first, try again with the new p,
            // and remember: p is automatically changed to the new value of head.
            work = (p ? p->work : -1); // Make sure to update work as well!
        }
        // Yup, great! Everything's done then, return the new task.
        return work; // Returns -1 if list is empty.
    }
};
```

**Edit:** The reason for using `shared_ptr` in combination with `atomic_*` functions is explained in the talk. In a nutshell: popping an item from the linked list might delete it from underneath someone traversing the list, or a different node might get allocated on the same memory address ([The ABA Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem)). Using `shared_ptr` will ensure any old readers will hold a valid reference to the original item.

As Herb explained, this makes the pop-function trivial to implement.

Comment: Partially thanks to your help I have finished the queue you might be interested to see it:). Please have a look at my edit of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Lock free in this kind of context where you have a shared resource (a work queue) is often going to be replaced by atomics and a CAS loop if you really dig deep.

The basic idea is rather simple to get a lock-free concurrent stack (edit: though perhaps a bit deceptively tricky as I made a goof in my first post -- all the more reason to appreciate a good lib). I chose a stack for simplicity but it doesn't take much more to use a queue instead.

Writing to the stack:

```
Create a new work item.
Loop Repeatedly:
    Store the top pointer to the stack.
    Set the work item's next pointer to the top of the stack.
    Atomic: Compare and swap the top pointer with the pointer to the work item.
            If this succeeds and returns the top pointer we stored, break out
            of the loop.
```

Popping from the stack:

```
 Loop:
     Fetch top pointer.
     If top pointer is not null:
         Atomic: CAS top pointer with next pointer.
         If successful, break.
     Else:
         (Optional) Sleep/Yield to avoid burning cycles.

 Process the item pointed to by the previous top pointer.
```

Now if you get really elaborate, you can stick in other work for the thread to do when a push or pop fails, e.g.

Comment: Partially thanks to your help I have finished the queue you might be interested to see it:). Please have a look at my edit of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

**I do not know how to do this in C++ 11 (or later); however, here is a solution for how to do it with C++ 98 and `boost (v1.50):**

This is obviously not a very useful example, it's only for demonstrative purposes:

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class WorkHandler
{
public:
    WorkHandler();
    ~WorkHandler();

    typedef boost::function<void(void)> Work; // the type of work we can handle
    void AddWork(Work w) { pThreadProcessing->post(w); }

private:
    void ProcessWork();

    boost::scoped_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> pThreadProcessing;
    boost::thread thread;
    bool runThread; // Make sure this is atomic
};

WorkHandler::WorkHandler()
: pThreadProcessing(new boost::asio::io_service), // create our io service
thread(&WorkHandler::ProcessWork, this), // create our thread
runThread(true) // run the thread
{
}

WorkHandler::~WorkHandler()
{
    runThread = false; // stop running the thread
    thread.join(); // wait for the thread to finish
}

void WorkHandler::ProcessWork()
{
    while (runThread) // while the thread is running
    {
        pThreadProcessing->run(); // process work
        pThreadProcessing->reset(); // prepare for more work
    }
}

int CalculateSomething(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    WorkHandler wh; // create a work handler
    // give it some work to do
    wh.AddWork(boost::bind(&CalculateSomething, 4, 5));
    wh.AddWork(boost::bind(&CalculateSomething, 10, 100));
    wh.AddWork(boost::bind(&CalculateSomething, 35, -1));
    Sleep(2000); // ONLY for demonstration! This just allows the thread a chance to work before we destroy it.
    return 0;
}
```

[`boost::asio::io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.thread_safety) is thread-safe, so you can post work to it without needing mutexes.

**NB: Although I haven't made the `bool runThread` atomic, for thread-safety it should be (I just don't have `atomic` in my c++)**